# Lettuce Webdriver can't find my link by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, lettuce

Lettuce picks up Behaviour Driven 'sentences' and executes code for use in tests.

There is a 'web-driver' that integrates this quite nicely with selenium.

My link is like so:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="/logout">Logout ?</a>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to use (either of) the steps described in [github readme](https://github.com/bbangert/lettuce_webdriver):

```
I should see a link to "Google" with the url "http://google.com/"
I should see a link that contains the text "Foobar" and the url "http://foobar.com/"
```

Which corresponds with this code:

```
@step('I should see a link to "(.*?)" with the url "(.*?)"$')
def should_see_link_text(step, link_text, link_url):
    assert_true(step,
                world.browser.find_element_by_xpath(str(
                    '//a[@href="%s"][./text()="%s"]' %
                    (link_url, link_text))))


@step('I should see a link that contains the text "(.*?)" '
      'and the url "(.*?)"$')
def should_include_link_text(step, link_text, link_url):
    return world.browser.find_element_by_xpath(str(
        '//a[@href="%s"][contains(., %s)]' %
        (link_url, link_text)))
```

But when I select my link in Chrome Dev Tools, it comes up as this x-path:

```
//*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/div/div[2]/a
```

Which is nothing like: `'//a[@href="%s"][contains(., %s)]'` or `'//a[@href="%s"][./text()="%s"]'`.

So which step should I use to capture my link, and do I need to change my html to match what is available in lettuce-webdriver (hint: this would not be good!)? Preferably without having to specify an id or class etc.

Edit: the Error LWD gives it:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lettuce\core.py", line 144, in __call__ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lettuce_webdriver\webdriver.py", line 107, in should_include_link_text(link_url, link_text)))
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href=\"/logout\"][contains(., \"Logout ?\")]"}
    Stacktrace:
        at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///D:/Users/CAStone/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkxv5zfva/extensi
ons/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9641:26)
        at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///D:/Users/CAStone/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkxv5zfva/extensions/fxdri
ver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9650:3)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///D:/Users/CAStone/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkxv5zfva/extensio
ns/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:16)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///D:/Users/CAStone/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkxv5zfva/extensions
/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///D:/Users/CAStone/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkxv5zfva/extensions/fxdriv
er@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

What worries me is the auto-escaping of my `"selector":"//a[@href=\"/logout\"][contains(., \"Logout ?\")]"` snip. If it's looking for the exact string of `\"/logout\"` and `\"Logout ?\"` then it clearly won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that logging in the django's `client` class, will not effect selenium. So the page selenium sees is not logged in.

The reason my 'I'm logged in' step fails is because I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I would rely directly on [the link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text):

```
world.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Logout ?')
```

or:

```
world.browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Logout')
```

Comment: And I assume with a custom step in my `*step.py` file? I'd still like to know why this doesn't work....

Comment: @Pureferret yup, custom step. Well, the `should_include_link_text` step doesn't work at least because there are missing quotes around `%s`.

Comment: Alex, I've just thrown my whole html page into http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx with `//a[@href="/logout"][contains(.,"Logout ?")]` and it finds it fine. The error message implies it's doing some crazy quote-escapage which might be the issue.

Comment: How would I guarantee that the elem brought back by `find_element_by_link_text` links to `\logout` ?

Comment: Actually it looks like as I'm not actually logged in (despite a 'client.login()'), the html I get doesn't contain that xpath.